# Two types of symbols in a lexer

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, lexer

I am trying to define a consistent terminology for Lexing tokens. For example, I can have the following two tokens:

```
DOLLAR = 'DOLLAR';
DOLLAR = '$';
```

Or:

```
STRING = 'STRING';
STRING = '"' + [^"]+ '"';
```

The first word I am most comfortable calling the "keyword" (like in SQL) as the word itself is always itself wrapped in quotes. What would be a good name for the more-abstract pattern? My thinking was:

- Both can be considered "tokens".
- The `$` can sometimes be an operator, but not always, for example, `(`.
- Both can be considered "symbols".

Perhaps the most informal way for me to state is that One is an english **word** and the other is not a word, it is an abstract **symbol** -- even though, technically speaking, both are symbols.

What might be a good distinction between the two?

Comment: '$' is a special character. The 2nd rule for STRING defines a string literal. If you want keywords, don't put them in quotes.

Comment: @user207421 I meant my lexer has two types of words -- keywords and symbolic character(s). What would be a good way to distinguish the two?

Comment: @samuel: That's really between you and your parser generator. Personally, I think token names for literal tokens should be avoided to the extent possible. The only interesting feature of a literal token is its spelling; the parser generator I usually use lets me just write `"$"` and `"string"`; nothing could be clearer than that. Once the AST has been built, tokens should no longer be of much interest; what's interesting is the type of each semantic node, which is only casually related to the tokens used to define that node.

Comment: In some parsing architectures, where the lexical analyser and the parser are built separately, it's necessary to name literal tokens so that the lexical analyser code can communicate to the parser code. But in many modern languages, including recent versions of C++, it's possible to use the token spelling as a compile-time constant, obviating the need for an artificial name.

Comment: @rici thanks for the feedback. Out of curiosity for `the parser generator I usually use` -- do you use flex/bison, or other?

Comment: I use flex and bison, but with preprocessing to avoid the need for literal token names.

Comment: "my lexer has two types of words -- keywords and symbolic character(s)": practically all lexers have keywords and identifiers, if that's what you mean.